# How to ask Chromium where it is sending audio?

Tags: audio, alsa, chrome

I'm not hearing anything from the Chromium browser. `aplay -l` lists three devices:

```
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In other audio-playing software, such as Audacity, I hear audio if I choose `hw:0,0`, but not with `hw:0,1` or HDMI. (I have no HDMI devices at the moment.)

I suspect Chromium is sending audio to `hw:0,1` or HDMI. How can I determine, from Chromium itself, which audio output it believes it's using?

Changing it to `hw:0,0` is another matter for later.

Comment: if you are using pulseaudio, the gui `pavucontrol` will show in the output tab an animated VU meter of the device getting the audio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pavucontrol` to change the audio device of chromium:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```